# how to handle multiple websocket++ tabs/windows?

Tags: c++, websocket, sessionid, browser-tab, websocket++

I'm trying to create a site that uses websocket++ as its' total backbone, and I've just realized that I might have a dilemma if a user opens multiple tabs/windows.

I'm writing [spa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) style, where all html and most css & js are loaded up front, and whenever a user clicks a link like one of the stack links above, it simply slides away the old `div` and slides in the new.  This is easy with ajax, but anyone who does 100% ajax knows the hell of constant updating.

Websockets and websocket++ makes autoupdating and user tracking easy, but I don't know how to handle a situation where the user doesn't appreciate all of my spa programming and wants another tab/window lol.

If a user opens another tab/window, will websocket++ automatically assign the tab/window another `connection_hdl`?  If so, how can I ensure the user is logged into the new tab/window?  If not, how can I separate the user tracking for each tab/window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every connection to a WebSocket++ server will get its own unique `connection_hdl`. This will happen if you open two WebSocket's from one application or the same application in multiple tabs/windows/computers.

Associating a given connection with a user is a pretty broad question. In short, like with non-websocket methods, you'll need to send along a username/password or session token to the server for each connection. If you want a single sign-on like effect between different tabs/windows you can use the browser's persistent client side storage (cookies, local storage, etc) to store those session tokens.

Comment: @zaphoyd see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21749338/jetty-websockets-share-connection-among-many-tabs please